# Question on product topology: closures, interiors, and sets of limit points

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Please if i define a topology $\sigma$ by the empty set and all $\Omega_n=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, |y|\geq n\}, n\in \mathbb{N}$

How to find $\overline{\{(3,0)\}}$, $\overset{\circ}{\overbrace{\{(3,0)}\}}$ and $(\mathbb{N}\times\{\frac12\})'$

I think that $\overset{\circ}{\overbrace{\{(3,0)}\}}=\emptyset$

To find $\overline{\{(3,0)\}}$ i find All closed sets which are $$\mathbb{R}^2~\text{and all}~ A_n=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, |y|<n\}$$

I see that Closed sets containing $(3,0)$ are $A_1,A_2,...$ and the smallest is $A_1$ so $$ \overline{\{(3,0)\}}=A_1$$

Now i need to fins $(\mathbb{N}\times\{\frac12\})'$ we say that $$x\in B'\Longleftrightarrow \forall V\in \mathcal{V}_x, (V\setminus\{x\})\cap B\neq \emptyset$$

I know that $(\mathbb{N}\times \{\frac12\})'\subset \overline{\mathbb{N}\times\{\frac12\}}$

**I think that $\overline{\mathbb{N}\times\{\frac12\}}=A_1$ but I don't know if all $(x,y)\in A_1$ then $(x,y)\in (\mathbb{N}\times\{\frac12\})'$**

**So please What is $(\mathbb{N}\times\{\frac12\})'$?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Does $B'$ in your notation denote the set of limit points of $B$? Perhaps you could work directly from the definition you wrote down.

Pick any $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$. Using $\lfloor|y| \rfloor $ to denote the largest integer less than or equal to $|y|$, the open sets containing $(x,y)$ are $\Omega_0,\  \dots \ ,\ \Omega_{\lfloor |y| \rfloor}$.

If $|y|< 1$, the only open set containing $(x,y)$ is $\Omega_0$. Clearly, $\Omega_0 \backslash (x,y)$ has non-empty intersection with $\mathbb N \times \{ \frac 1 2 \}$. So if $|y|< 1$, then $(x,y)$ is a limit point of $\mathbb N \times \{ \frac 1 2 \}$.

I'll leave you to think about whether $(x,y)$ is a limit point of $\lfloor|y| \rfloor $ when $|y| \geq 1$. You can use the same method.

Comment: So the conclusion is $(\mathbb{N}\times\{\frac12\})'=A_1$ right ?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: I need your help for an other question , the question is draw $P=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, x^2+y^2-6y+5=0\}$ and find  $\overline{P}$ , i draw $P$ but i think that it dosent intersect any $\Omega_n$

Comment: Ignore the $\Omega_n$'s. Find all $A_n$'s that contain $P$. Take the intersection of all such $A_n$'s. It's similar to the problem that you already solved.

Comment: from the graphe it intersect all $A_n$ with $n\geq2$, it intersect $A_2,A_3,...$ but it doesn't intersect $A_1$

Comment: How i can sent you the graphe ?

Comment: It's fine, the graph is a circle with centre $(0,3)$ and radius $2$. So I agree that $\bar P$ is $A_2$.

Comment: after that it ask about neighborhood system of (1,1), i think that it is  $\Omega_1$ the smallest open neighborhood containing (1,1) right ?

Comment: I think so. I've got to go now. Good luck!

Comment: $A_2$ do not contain $P$ , t/he smallest closed set containig $R$ is $A_6$ what do you think about that

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right! $P$ goes as "high" as $y=5$.